# How do I get to Cape Canaveral from Orlando?

Tags: public-transport, tours, orlando

I'm looking to visit Cape Canaveral in early December, but we'll be based in Orlando.  Specifically we're interested in the Kennedy Space Centre.  Apparently it's a 50 minute drive.  Is renting a car the only option to visit the Space Centre from Orlando?  Are there public transport options?  Do day tours leaving from Orlando exist, and are they worth it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Kennedy Space Center](http://www.kennedyspacecenter.com) is located just north of Cape Canaveral, and is definitely worth a visit.

The best time to visit is obviously when there is a launch occurring at Cape Canaveral.  The Space Shuttles may no longer be flying, but there are still regular rocket launches (the next occurring in just over a day!), however it's still worth going at any time.

There are bus tours available - I can't recommend any as I've never been on one although Google finds several including [this one](http://www.kennedyspacecentertours.net) - but I would strongly recommend renting a car. Not only will this give you much more flexibility both around time and exactly where you go, but it'll probably work out to be cheaper, especially if there's more than one of you.  Orlando is the biggest rental car market in the world, so it's not hard to rent there!

There is no public transport to KSC.